# why do I have 2 core.editor in git?

Tags: git

When I run `git config -l` I get 2 `core.editor` appearing
The correct one (notepad.exe) is in .gitconfig as I added it there
But unfortunately the other one is coming up. How can I remove it?
and what file is it stored in?

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=false
core.editor='C:/windows/system32/notepad.exe'
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
alias.hist=log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
core.editor='C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
gui.wmstate=normal
gui.geometry=1061x860+80+51 171 192
```

Comment: Do you have two `core.editor` in your user `.gitconfig` file? If not, then do you have a global `.gitconfig` file? If you do, then that's no problem because local settings for the same variable override global settings. Is this actually causing a problem for you?

Comment: @Greg Hewgill. Thanks, I dont have 2 core.editor in .gitconfig. it is causing a problem as I dont have notepadd++, and I'd also like to understand what is going on. I have a global .gitconfig file whcih has the notepad.exe file in it. What file will the other one be stored in?

Comment: In your repository config? <your-repository>/.git/config

Comment: There can be a global one, stored in some system-defined location (I don't know where that would be on Windows, but you seem to have found it already). There is one stored in your home directory that affects all repositories under your user account. Finally, there is `.git/config` which is stored in *each* repository (so you can change options on a per-repository basis).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git looks for configuration settings in three locations:

```
/etc/gitconfig
~/.gitconfig
.git/config
```

These are the system-wide, per-user and per-repository settings, respectively. More specific settings override more general ones (e.g. per-repo overrides per-user). The convenient way to get/set them is to use `git config --system`, `git config --global` and `git config` .

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive and simple explanation. Culprit was in the global one (c:\users\username\.gitconfig). What I thought was the global one was actually the system one.

Comment: Bingo! This was what I needed. I set Notepad++ as my global core editor.